# encoding php output to produce a new line without html

Tags: php, html

I want to produce an output such as this on an html page:

```
111
222
333
44
555
```

without using html at all. I tried using \n\r but that doesnt work. I am looking for some character ascii or utf that will drop a line and produce that output as I echo it with php.

A possible solution that I thought to send a browser a text or something instead of html, in the head :

> ```
> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text; charset=UTF-8">
> ```

I am not sure what other solutions there are ..

Comment: That's like saying I want to shave a cat without cutting it's hair. Answer: Magic.

Comment: @MarkBaker Wrong. You used HTML.

Comment: try `style="white-space: pre"` at the wrapping element

Comment: why to downvote.. READ :"A possible solution that I thought...." .. if i knew the solution..I wouldnt have asked you

Comment: iambriansreed .. lol..cats dont  have hair..they have got fur..

Comment: maybe you should define clearly what you want to do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to output a text file then change the content type in the HTTP header like this

```
header("Content-type: text/plain");

echo "some\nplain\ntext";
```

-*you can't mix this with HTML though, it's all or nothing* :)

Comment: 'without using HTML at all' => not a HTML page => OP probably wants to output plain text generated by a PHP script :)

Comment: He talks about "<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text; charset=UTF-8">"

Comment: Mention that your code above is the only code to put in the page. No HTML at all. I will up vote then.

Answer (score -1):

Wrap the output in `<pre></pre>` and then whenever you want to have a line break, use `PHP_EOL`:

```
echo $string . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: If you are outputting HTML in your headers, then your output is HTML. You don't have to output HTML from PHP, that's just the convention. Why don't you create a script that outputs with a mimetype of text/plain?

Comment: That's the logical conclusion but still OP says "...on an html page..."

Comment: You can use a form textarea element and output the text into that, but if its HTML you can't just magically expect it to render as plain text without telling it how to do that (with HTML).

Comment: Sorry @cam8001 textarea is html.

Comment: READ MY LAST LINE...."I am not sure what other solutions there are .." .. how did I confuse any of you